# Design Decision properties vs variables

Tags: ios, objective-c

Lets say i have a UISegmentedSwitch for the User to set Metric or Imperial Measure

I could then test for its state in various part of the code,
but if the condition was what i thought it was, have i wasted my time (and cycles) in the asking?

In other languages I have normally set a variable/flag as a multiplier, the default being 1, ( no change as a result)  and the other being what conversion is required ( e.g. 3.048 ).

that way there is no need to test, and if there are other things happening at the calculation its not an additional nesting of methods.

But does it get into global variable territory? Is it so bad if there is only one such flag even though it will be required in a number of places?

Perhaps I should create a custom class with just one property, or make it a property of the viewController, but is the cpu processing involved in all that just as taxing on battery life or UI responsiveness?

whats 'the usual' here?

Comment: The "usual" is that it is one simple operation on modern hardware which is very fast so it doesn't matter from that perspective.  Using a multiplier is a very easy to understand concept that works great and defining it as a constant is a very reasonable thing to do!

Comment: not a very well constructed question i know, as the segmented switch could be a property of the view controller, i just realised.  Oh, there's replies here already..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the "normal" here would be to use [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] and have it persist.

You are making decisions in the code in other places based on this value.  It would also seem likely you would like to have this value persist between uses of the App, so that their choice would be maintained.

Referring to it as `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kUsesMetric];` is what would be "the norm" in my programming group.

Answer (score 1):

There are those who believe that global variables are evil, and like most anything else, if they're abused they can be.  But the idea that a variable like this shouldn't be made global is silly.

If you're going to be using it heavily and restricting it to read-only except for the one location, I'd forget the naysayers and go with it.  If it isn't going to be that heavily referenced, you could make it a property that gets passed around from class to class, but that is a pain.

Another alternative is a singleton to hold "globals" as shown here:

http://maniacdev.com/2009/07/global-variables-in-iphone-objective-c/

IMO, the excitement about occasional use of globals is overdone.  There are times and places where it just makes sense.

Comment: *There are times and places where it just makes sense.* And this is definitely not one of them.  Applications should seek to minimize state, especially global state, whenever possible.  There's a reason why we have so many operators and symbols to indicate scope in nearly every language ever written.

Comment: i like this answer, but I'm going to give 'the tick' to HalR because he's thought ahead to future functionality. I'm only at the beginnings of this project